# Exposing functions in js service format: Will this work?

Tags: angularjs, return, factory, angularjs-service

Will this work?

**Service.js**

```
(function() {
    var module = angular.module('myApp');

    var myService = function () { 

        var myServiceMethod = function () { //some code };

        return factory;
    };

    var module = angular.module('blueBoxApp');
    module.factory('myService', myService);
}())
```

**Controller.js**

```
(function() {
    var module = angular.module('myApp');

    var myController = function (myService) { 

        myService.myServiceMethod();
    };

    module.Controller('myController', myController);
}())
```

Right now, in my service, I am returning an object containing the names of each service. Can I just return the factory and have access to them? Or do I have to prefix each service method with `thisFactoryObj`?

Comment: In the example, `asnServices` is not defined. You should start by reading a style guide such as [John Papa Angular 1 Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#angular-1-style-guide)

Comment: @georgeawg that was a typo. I fixed it.